How to sync multiple Android media MusicPlayers with low latency
I’m developing an Android app that needs to play five audio tracks of a song simultaneously. I'm currently using the Android MediaPlayer package for playback. However, precise synchronization is critical, as the latency between tracks must not exceed 25ms. Sometimes I achieve this timing, but more often the latency exceeds 25ms, leading to noticeable desynchronization. I’ve experimented with coroutines, which I left in my code example, but that didn’t improve the results.
lateinit var songTracks: Array<MediaPlayer>

private fun prepareMediaPlayers() {
    songTracks = arrayOf(
        MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track1),
        MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track2),
        MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track3),
        MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track4),
        MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track5)
    )

}

private val onPlaying = fun() {
    prepareMediaPlayers()
    // Does not play synchronously 
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { songTracks[0].start() }
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { songTracks[1].start() }
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { songTracks[2].start() }
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { songTracks[3].start() }
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { songTracks[4].start() }
}

I also tried alternatives like ExoPlayer, which produced similar issues, and SoundPool, which seemed promising, but is unsuitable for longer audio tracks (up to 5 minutes). How can I achieve precise synchronization for multi-track audio playback on Android?

To my understanding MediaPlayers don't do low-latency. For your desired latency you are in the realm of games or Digital Audio Workstation software. Unclear if you've seen: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio  https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/audio-latency and https://github.com/google/oboe

Thank you for sharing these documentations, I was unaware of them. This sounds more in-line to what I need from the post. I'll try implementing these solution.
